# How to use callback function to make sure a div got hidden only after the function execution is complete

Tags: javascript, html

I am adding a functionality to existing code in which I want that one div get visible (containing wait symbol) and after that function is executed then only the div should get hidden. but this function is making some asynchronous calls . so I don't get how to keep that div there

```
 function bounceRunning()
 {
     var strBounce = confirm("Do you really want to bounce all the running interfaces?");
     if (strBounce == true) {
        idDivread.style.display='';
        var strMsg;
        var rows = document.all('KnlTbl').rows;
        //loop through our interfaces
        for(var i = 0;i < rows.length;i++)
        {
            //is this interface running?
            if(rows[i].cells[1].innerText == 'Running')
            {
                bounce(i,true);
            }
        }

        //display any message the bounce manager may have
        displayBounceMsg();
        idDivread.style.display='none';
    }   
}
```

How to make sure that this div remains there till display bounce function is complete.and this code is in quirk mode so don't worry about document.getElementById

Comment: Depends on what `displayBounceMsg` does exactly.

Comment: the is some asynchronous calls over there

Comment: The make `displayBounceMsg` accept a callback and put `idDivread.style.display='none';` inside the callback. Execute the callback when the asynchronous call is done.

Comment: please show me the syntax

Comment: `function displayBounceMsg(callback) { .... callback(); ... };` and `displayBounceMsg(function() { idDivread.style.display='none'; });`. Nothing special, just calling and passing functions.